# What is the purpose of `s`?

Tags: normal-mode

What is the intended use case for the <kbd>s</kbd> command in normal mode?

I've been looking at it for some time, inadvertently pressing <kbd>s</kbd>, but can't find any use case that would make sense for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think there's a more specific use mode than to delete the character under the cursor and enter insert mode. By using a number modifier you can delete several characters before entering insert mode. E.g. if you want to change `foobar` into `fubar`, then I would set to cursor to `f`, and press `3sfu`. Of course, you don't need to use `s`, you could also do e.g. `ctbu`. I guess you can always get away without using `s`. That being said, I use `s` very often.

Comment: I use it to avoid "delete something then enter insert" separately.  It's nice to be able to hit v for highlight, then 4e to highlight 4 words, then hit s and start typing.

Comment: I don't use `s` that way because I don't like moving  too often that far up the keyboard for editing stuff. I would use `c` for that. That being said, I was wondering if there's some other intended use case. It just fells against the vim way I got used to.

Comment: @Dumitru Can you touch type numbers? Cause that's the only reason I see to "don't like moving too ofthen that far up the keyboard".

Comment: @user1685095, Yeah, I can. What do you mean with the only reason? The inability or the ability?

Comment: @Dumitru Inability.

Comment: Maybe that makes sense. But for me it breaks the flow for me to reach for numbers while using thim.

Answer (score 16):

`s` is short for `cl` which is mentioned in `help s`:

```
["x]s                   Delete [count] characters [into register x] and start
                        insert (s stands for Substitute).  Synonym for "cl"
                        (not linewise).
```

I've mapped `s` to my own command and haven't missed the default 'substitute' so far.

Answer (score 12):

In normal mode:

- `s` same as `cl`
- `S` same as `cc`

In visual mode:

- `s` same as `c`
- `S` is remapped by vim-surround to a (very useful) surround operator.

I don't see any clear advantage of having `s` for substitute when there is already a `c` for change.
I'm using `nmap s ys` in my `init.vim` (or `.vimrc`) to use `s` as a surround operator instead.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! One use for `s` is to replace a single character with more characters (since `r` only works with one character replacements). That said, I rarely use it…